# want to save JPg or png according to default setting of window in java

Tags: java

```
Dimension size = contentPane.getSize();
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height,
                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics();
contentPane.paintAll(graphics2D);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", f);
```

In this code i can save form as jpg file but in my client window it is not opening.

He has to right click and open it in paint(And he doesn't want this, he wants by double clicking it should open not by right click).

Is there any code available in java that I can check default setting or I can set default setting as jpg so that my any client can open it by double clicking.

Whatever is the default setting my program should save according to default setting(either in png or jpg )

Kindly Give the suggestion to me

Comment: so you want to change the file association for jpg files?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What default settings are you looking for exactly?

Comment: What file name are you saving to image to?

Comment: default settings of window.If we want to open jpg image in window its not opening.It can be opened by right clicking the image and choose the "open with" option. But I want it should be opened by double clicking in any window.Hope you got my point.